# ie7 not displaying css rule unless I turn it on and off again in developer tools

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The "Go" submit button wont display in ie7 until I tick the rule on and off again in the developer tools.

```
<div id="footerNewsletter">

                <p><?php echo $text_newsletter_signup; ?></p>
                <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="cm_signup(); return false;">
                    <input name="Email" id="Email" value="<?php echo $text_email_address; ?>" type="text" onclick="this.value='';" />
                    <?php /*<a href="#" id="newsletterSubmit" ><span><?php echo 'Go'; ?></span></a> */ ?>

                    <input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" name="Name" value="Go" />
                </form> 

                <p id="nl_return"></p>
      </div>
```

and the CSS

```
#footerNewsletter {
background: #a29061;
width: 274px;
height: 46px;
color: #fff;
float: left;
padding: 8px 13px;
margin-left:20px;
position:relative;

}

#footerNewsletter {
background: #a29061;
width: 274px;
height: 46px;
color: #fff;
float: left;
padding: 8px 13px;
margin-left:20px;
position:relative;

}
#footerNewsletter p {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 90px;
height: 45px;
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
color: #fff;
float: left;
}
#footerNewsletter input {
float: right;
height:25px;
color: #a29061;
border: 0;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
background: #fff;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 158px;
}
input.newsletter-submit{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #54301A !important;
color: #60C5BA !important;
display: block !important;
float: right !important;
font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif !important;
font-size: 13px !important;
margin: 10px 0 0 !important;
padding: 0px 0px !important;
position: absolute;
right: 10px !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
width: 30px !important;
height:25px !important;
z-index: 10 !important;
bottom:19px !important;
}
.newsletter-submit:hover {
background: #60c5ba !important;
color: #54301a !important;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Its fine in all other browsers, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're combining a float on the input along with trying to position it absolutely. Hav a look at changing that to just one method and see if it helps.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining a float on the input along with trying to position it absolutely.

Have a look at changing that to just one method and see if it helps.